# Different target URLs for user roles

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security

How to configure different target URLs after login based on user roles? I'm using Spring security plugin.

Comment: try to search for that issue in stackoverflow. there are many questions facing your issue. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968210/grails-spring-security-redirect-after-login-success-failure

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. I want to send users to different views after succesfull login depending on their roles. For example after successfull login user with ROLL_USER role is redirected to userIndex.gsp and user with ROLL_ADMIN role is redirected to adminIndex.gsp. This is one solution I guess: [link](http://omarello.com/2011/09/grails-custom-target-urls-after-login/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can define a defaultTargetUrl just like Denis mention or like in this site: [Grails spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968210/grails-spring-security-redirect-after-login-success-failure) like hitty5 said.

And you can put the logic of the redirect depending on the role of the user in the response of that default request.

With grails:

in config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/login/loggedIn'
```

in LoginController (because that controller contains the default action configured)

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_DEFAULT'])
    def loggedIn = {
        Usuario user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        def roleDefault = Rol.findByAuthority("ROLE_DEFAULT")
        if(user.authorities.contains(roleDefault))
            redirect(controller: 'factura')
        def roleAdmin = Rol.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        if(user.authorities.contains(roleAdmin))
            redirect(controller: 'noticia')
    }
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form-login
            login-processing-url="/user/login"
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/loginsuccess"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailure" />
```

Why you couldn't do redirect to another page after check user role in Spring controller which mapped on the loginsuccess url?